# Generating function for the solutions of equation $ 2x_1 + 4x_2 = n$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Let's denote $h_n$ as the number of soulutions of the following equation:

$$ 2x_1 + 4x_2 = n$$

where $x_i \in \mathbb N$.

Find generating function of the sequence $h_n$ and calculate $h_{2000}$.

I've found the generating function:

$$\frac{1}{1-x^2}\cdot \frac{1}{1-x^4},$$
but I don't know how to expand it now. Any ideas?

Comment: first of  all $n$ is even ,alternate form is  $x_1+2*x=k$  where  $k=n/2$  now that  equation has infinite solution,because   there is not constrant that  $k$ should be  even

Comment: what kind of notation is $N$?

Comment: $N$ is natural. Sorry, maybe I should have used another notation.

Comment: use $Z$ for  integers   or $Z+$ for positive  intergers no problems btw

Comment: number of all solution of above  equation is ifinite

Comment: I don't understand. Let's say that $n=8$. There are three solutions: $x_1 =0, x_2 =2; x_1 =2, x_2 =1;x_1 =4, x_2 =0$

Comment: so it means that  $N$ is constant right?

Comment: @dato: $n$ is variable. *For a given value of $n$*, the number $h_n$ (as a function of $n$) is the number of solutions to $2x_1 + 4x_2 = n$ (for that $n$).

Comment: but is  $0$ natural?as i know natural number start from $1$

Comment: if not in ncase of  $n=8$ there i only  one  slution $x_1=2$  and $x_2=1$   or

Comment: we can't  say that  $n$  or $x_1,x_2$  can be  negative,it is real  infinity  solution

Comment: please see my friend    if i am going by correct way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you observed, if the generating function for $h_n$ is $$f(x) = h_0 + h_1x + h_2x^2 + h_3x^3 + \dots + h_nx^n + \dots,$$
then $$f(x) = (1 + x^2 + x^4 + x^6 + \dots)(1 + x^4 + x^8 + x^{12} + \dots) = \frac{1}{1-x^2}\frac{1}{1-x^4}$$

To actually get the coefficients of $x^n$ in the above, we resort to [partial fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction). The denominator of the above can be factored into irreducible factors, using the identity $1-y^2 = (1+y)(1-y)$, as $(1+x)(1-x)(1+x^2)(1+x)(1-x) = (1+x)^2(1-x)^2(1+x^2)$. Therefore, by the general theory of partial fractions, $f(x)$ can be written as
$$f(x) = \frac{A}{1+x\vphantom{(1+x)^2}} + \frac{B}{(1+x)^2} + \frac{C}{1-x\vphantom{(1-x)^2}} + \frac{D}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{Ex + F}{1+x^2} + \frac{Gx + H}{(1+x^2)^2}$$
where $A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H$ are constants. Using [various painful tricks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction#Example_3) it's possible to determine the constants, but because I'm not the one doing this as homework, I'll just turn to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%281-x%5E2%29+1%2F%281-x%5E4%29) which says that
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{4(1+x)} + \frac{1}{8(1+x)^2} + \frac{1}{4(1-x)} + \frac{1}{8(1-x)^2} + \frac{1}{4(1+x^2)}.$$

Here the five terms are, respectively, 
$\frac14 \sum_n{(-1)^n x^n}$ and
$\frac18 \sum_n {(-1)^n (n+1)x^n}$ and
$\frac14 \sum_n x^n$ and
$\frac18 \sum_n (n+1)x^n$ and
$\frac14 \sum_n{(-1)^n x^{2n}}$,
so $$h_{2000} = \frac14 (-1)^{2000} + \frac18 (-1)^{2000}2001 + \frac14 + \frac18 2001 + \frac14 (-1)^{1000} = 501.$$

[That's the answer, but as you can see the whole thing is a quite painful process that I wouldn't wish on my worst enemy, which is why I keep saying that generating functions are *not* the best way to solve these counting problems, despite the dazzle of the first step where you get some cute expression for the generating function.]

---

Edit: Just for contrast, the solution without generating functions: Clearly $n$ must be even, so we're counting solutions to $x + 2y = n/2$ in the nonnegative integers. From $0 \le 2y \le n/2$ we have $0 \le y \le \left\lfloor \frac{n/2}{2} \right\rfloor$, and for each such $y$ there is a unique $x = n/2 - 2y$ as solution. So the number of solutions (for even $n$) is $1 + \left\lfloor \frac{n/2}{2} \right\rfloor$, which for $n = 2000$ is $1 + \left\lfloor \frac{1000}{2} \right\rfloor = 501$.

The solution without generating functions is not always this simple, but I think this is a good example of how going down the generating functions route can be a bad idea if you want exact numbers (as opposed to asymptotic estimates, say).

Comment: for  instance,using some exmaple of variable  $n$ we may see  some dependence or relationship between  number of solutions of each  $n$

Comment: Yes, that case using generating function is not required, but the point is to prepare for my mid-term test:) All in all, thanks a lot for your response!

Comment: Regarding your bracketed comment, and aside from the conceptual interest of GFs, do you have any opinion as to the "validity" of directly using a computer simulation for counting problems, such as [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2626500/152225), vis-a-vis going through the math exercise of producing the GF, and eventually resorting to Mathematica?

Comment: @AntoniParellada Depends on what you mean by a computer simulation. If you write a program that counts exactly, then (assuming the program has no bugs) you can say your answer is valid, though ideally you'd get independent confirmation by someone else writing a different program that uses a different approach.

Comment: I meant Monte Carlo.

Comment: @AntoniParellada Then I guess you need to do the probability analysis, until you have something like “with probability 93%, the error is at most 0.5%” or whatever. (Basically you need to know how many times you need to run your simulation until you're reasonably confident the answer is reasonably accurate.) At that point it might end up being easier to do the actual analysis. :-)

Comment: @AntoniParellada I have posted an answer there with a slick (IMO) approach using generating functions; take a look. I am curious about your Monte Carlo simulation: what does it do exactly? (I can think of an exact counting approach that simply generates all sequences of pens, and counts how many have no two consecutive the same. But I'm blanking on how to come up with a Monte Carlo simulation… ah, do you generate some sequences of pens at random, check how many are “good”, and use that to estimate the ratio, multiply by the total number (which you calculate in some other direct way)?

Comment: +1 for your answer. I just set up a vector with the pens of different colors, and direct the computer to arrange them in the form specified (no same color side to side), but in an otherwise random fashion. I did it two different ways $10^6$ times, and simply looked for unique vectors. The result was spot on, as I posted under comments of the OP.

Answer (score 2):

So assuming your generating function is correct we can see that:
$$\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n,\ a_n = \text{ 1 if 2 divides $n$, 0 otherwise}$$

$$\frac{1}{1-x^4}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n,\ b_n = \text{ 1 if 4 divides $n$, 0 otherwise}$$

So we can use this to calculate the product:

$$\frac{1}{1-x^2}\cdot \frac{1}{1-x^4}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n$$

Where $c_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k}$, we can see $a_kb_{n-k} = $ 1 if 2 divides $k$ and 4 divides $n-k$, 0 otherwise.
We can see that for odd $n$ this always evaluates to 0 (sanity check: this makes sense!), and for even $n$ we have 1 only when $n-k$ is divisible by 4. So for even $c_n$ is simply the number of $0\leq k\leq n$ such that $n-k$ is divisible by 4. With a little bit of thought we can see that this is $\lfloor \frac n 4 \rfloor +1$.

So putting in $n=2000$ gives us 501!

Comment: i did not understand one  think.why it should be  polynomials?and also we  can we determine which polynomial will be relevant?

Comment: This solution, BTW, is equivalent to forgetting about generating functions and doing it by hand: let $a_n = [n\text{ is $2x_1$ for some $x_1$}]$ and $b_n = [n\text{ is $4x_2$ for some $x_2$}]$, then they are $a_n = [2|n]$ and $b_n = [4|n]$ respectively as you got, and the number of solutions to $n = 2x_1 + 4x_2$ is $\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kb_{n-k}$ and the rest as in your paragraph. :-)

Comment: This solution relies fairly heavily on the use of generating functions (formal power series), they're a bit tricky to get used to, and so I recommend the free book generatingfunctionology by Herbert Wilf:
http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Yeah generating functions are pretty useful, but I guess in this case totally unnecessary!

Comment: @AlexJBest I wish I could accept also your answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

let us think     n as following variables

$n=6$

only  one solution $x_1=1$   and  $x_2=1$

$n=8$

again one solution

$x_1=2$  and  $x_2=1$

$n=10$

now we have following solutions

$x_1=3$   and   $x_2=1$,second pair would be  $x_1=1$ and $x_2=2$

now take $n=12$

$x_1=4$  and   $x_2=1$   $x_1=2$ and $x_2=2$
so   sequences is for this case $1, 1, 2,  2$  i am not sure that there is  any  clear  relationship,let  check again

let us add  two more case

$n=14$
solutions are

$x_1=3$   and $x_2=2$  and  $x_1=1$  and $x_2=3$   and $x_1=5$  and $x_2=1$,so there is    three solution.now we get

$1,1,2,2,3$

let take  $n=16$

we have following pairs

1)$x_1=2$    and $x_2=3$

2)$x_1=4$     and $x_2=2$

3) $x_1=6$      and $x_2=1$

so i think that  for more and more even numbers,it increases by  1(number of solution) and
keeps  it  for the next even number too,like it for example increases  number of solution by $1$ for $n=22$ for exmaple and also  it keeps this amount for $n=24$

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the generating function is:
\begin{align}
f(z) &= \frac{1}{1 - z^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - z^4} \\
     &= \frac{1}{4 (1 - z^2)} + \frac{1}{4 (1 + z^2)} + \frac{1}{2 (1 - z^2)^2}
\end{align}
(this results from recognizing the generating function as a fraction in $z^2$, and splitting as such into partial fractions). Thus the expansion is:
\begin{align}
f(z) &= \frac{1}{4} \sum_{k \ge 0} \left( 1 + (-1)^k \right) z^{2 k} 
          + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k \binom{-2}{k} z^{2 k} \\
     &= \frac{1}{4} \sum_{k \ge 0} \left( 1 + (-1)^k \right) z^{2 k}
          + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{n + 1}{1} z^{2 k} \\
     &= \frac{1}{4} \sum_{k \ge 0} \left( 1 + (-1)^k \right) z^{2 k}
          + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k \ge 0} (k + 1) z^{2 k}
\end{align}
This gives the coefficients:
$$
h_n = \begin{cases}
         0                                           & \text{$n$ odd} \\
         \left\lfloor \frac{n}{4} \right\rfloor + 1  & \text{$n$ even}
      \end{cases}
$$
Thus $h_{2000} = 501$.