# team needs 14 runs to win

Tags: combinatorics

In a match a team needs 14 runs to win in the last over to win the match
(i.e.) exactly 14 run, assuming that all runs are made off the bat and the batsmen can not score more than 4 runs off any ball. find the number of ways in which team just manages to win the match i.e.  scores exactly 14 runs.

My attempt to the solution

We can take 3 cases

2 dot balls
1 dot balls
0 dot balls

Only the 1st case is easy to solve next are very difficult to calculate.

Comment: For those unfamiliar, the first part likely relates to [cricket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket).  What is the actual problem here?  (Are you trying to count the number of ways of obtaining 14 runs?)  It's natural to think the team would still win even if they scored 15 or more runs too.  The second part of this question is totally disconnected from the first, and should be a separate question.

Comment: ya 2nd part is a new question.!!

Comment: '(i.e.) exactly 14 run' limited the scope and left no ambiguity in my mind. i was about to drop my answer before this got put on hold.

Comment: Plz can u tell..now i have edited this. Niw the language is clear

Comment: "2 dot balls 1 dot balls 0 dot balls" Whatever does that mean?

Comment: Ist case means there are 2 dot balls in 6 balls.       IInd case means there is 1 dot ball in 6 balls.      IIIrd case means there is no dot ball in 6balls

Comment: There are a lot of Cricket terms here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_cricket_terms is a glossary for those so interested. A dot ball is a delivery of a ball such that no runs are gained from it. There are 6 balls to an "over" - this aint gonna be easy!

Comment: @GerryMyerson: A "dot ball" is a ball in which no runs are scored. The question is to find the number of solutions $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6)$ such that $0 \le x_i \le 4$ and $\sum x_i = 14$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question, you want the number of ways of choosing six integers $a_1,\ldots,a_6$ with $0 \le a_i \le 4$ and $\sum_1^6 a_i = 14$. The answer is the coefficient of $x^{14}$ in the polynomial $(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)^6$, which you can ask [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) to compute.

This assumes that you don't need to have the team win the match on the very last ball.

Comment: can u explain this...that how does coefficient of dis works..?

Comment: Each $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ represents one delivery. The coefficient of $x^{14}$ in the product is the number of ways of choosing a term $x^{a_i}$ from each delivery so that the $a_i$ add up to 14.

Comment: can i get some theory on this..?

Comment: That's all I'm going to say.

Comment: ???????????????

Comment: maths lover, answering your question doesn't commit me to holding an unpaid seminar on generating functions. Go and expand the polynomial by hand, and you will find out for yourself.

Comment: i m asking a source for reading this

Comment: @mathslover [Generatingfuctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf) is pretty good.

Comment: I think for concrete problems like this (as opposed to asymptotics), an answer in terms of generating functions is a non-answer, and worse than nothing. It is **not** any easier to find (by hand) the coefficient of $x^{14}$ in $(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)^6$ than it is to solve the original problem; any techniques applicable to the former are also applicable to the latter. If anything, the "reduction" to generating functions has only made the problem slighty harder, by introducing potentially distracting details.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: If we're talking concrete vs abstract, you may have noticed that my approach was the one that gave the correct answer.

Comment: @TonyK: I don't see an answer. And did you compute the coefficient of $x^{14}$ in $(x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)^6$ by hand? (BTW, I meant concrete not as opposed to abstract, but in the sense of wanting an actual number instead of asymptotics: perhaps "finite" would have been a better word.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: You will find my answer in a comment to elbeardmorez's answer. And no, I didn't compute it by hand -- that's what elbeardmorez did, and they got it wrong :-)

Comment: @TonyK: Yes, what I said in my original comment was that when you want to compute an answer *by hand,* it doesn't help to use the machinery of generating functions. (Though if you're using computers, there too both are at equal levels of algorithmic complexity, being essentially the same problem.) See also instances like [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/350393/205) where the generating functions approach gets positively ridiculous in comparison.

Answer (score 3):

i'll be interested to see if there's a better way of doing this, but below is my brute force (systematic) attempt at getting the combinations. hopefully i didn't miss any.

4 4 4 2 0 0 | 6!/(3!2!) = 60
4 4 4 1 1 0 | 6!/(3!2!) = 60
4 4 3 3 0 0 | 6!/(2!2!2!) = 90
4 4 3 2 1 0 | 6!/2! = 360
4 4 3 1 1 1 | 6!/(2!3!) = 60
4 4 2 2 2 0 | 6!/(2!3!) = 60
4 4 2 2 1 1 | 6!/(2!2!2!) = 90
4 3 3 3 1 0 | 6!/3! = 120
4 3 3 2 2 0 | 6!/(2!2!) = 180 <- [edit: initially missed, spotted by TonyK]
4 3 3 2 1 1 | 6!/(2!2!) = 180
4 3 2 2 2 1 | 6!/3! = 120
4 2 2 2 2 2 | 6!/5! = 6
3 3 3 3 2 0 | 6!/4! = 30
3 3 3 3 1 1 | 6!/(4!2!) = 15
3 3 3 2 2 1 | 6!/(3!2!) = 60
3 3 2 2 2 2 | 6!/(2!4!) = 15

so 1506 ways to make exactly 14..

we're looking for unique combinations initially and then calculating the number of permutations for each. hopefully you can see the logic but..

starting with the most efficient way to make 14 (4 4 4 2), work on combinations based around modification of the last scoring bat (2 in this case), reduce by 1 and then 'compensate' by scoring (the same or less) for the remaining bat(s), and only where necessary (i.e where the tally < 14), and where possible (i.e. there are bats remaining in the over)

so (4 4 4 2 0 0) -> (4 4 4 1 1 0). and that exhausts the combinations for necessary scoring bats. we then reduce the last scoring bat >1 and continue as before. (4 4 4 1 1 0) -> (4 4 3 ? ? ?) so thus (4 4 3 3 0 0) gives 14. then (4 4 3 3 0 0) -> (4 4 3 2 ? ?) so (4 4 3 2 1 0) and so on and so on..

Comment: My method gives 1506 as the answer.

Comment: yes the answer is 1506

Comment: i'll look for mistakes, thanks

Comment: I checked your terms, so you probably just added them up wrong.

Comment: is the difference the 1st and 3rd terms ..the additional divisions by '2!' for the last two 0 scoring bats. so my solution requires 14 in 6 balls? yours, 4-6 balls?

Comment: I found it! -- you left out 4 3 3 2 2 0.

Comment: excellent. thanks. i'll edit the answer for the benefit of others but you get the credit here

Comment: @TonyK really interesting these different approaches. I would have argued for the approach here as brute force is easy and by the time you've been clever enough to figure out a better way you've already finished your brute force solution. But your approach shows that the clever way is also less error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the number of $6$-tuples with elements in $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ that sum to $14$ can be solved computationally in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) via:

```
S:=RestrictedPartitions(14+6,[0,1,2,3,4]+1,6)-1;
Sum(S,P->NrPermutationsList(P));
```

This finds the set $S$ of partitions of $20$ into $6$ integers in $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and subtracts $1$ from each coordinate.  Then for each element $P \in S$, it finds the number of ordered $6$-tuples that give rise to $P$ when unordered.

This return `1506` in agreement with the other answers.

---

*Comment*: One might also get the same answer using

```
S:=RestrictedPartitions(14,[0,1,2,3,4],6);
```

but this could be considered "cheating" (since `RestrictedPartitions` is not guaranteed to work correctly for partitions involving 0; e.g. `NrRestrictedPartitions(1,[0,1],2);` returns 0).